# R Shiny downloadHandler() save nothing

Tags: r, shiny, xlsx

in the ui.R nothing is different

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      downloadButton('downloadData','Save Results')
    )
)
```

in the server.R

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function () { paste0("output", ".xlsx", sep='') },
   content = function (file) { 
  fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
  write.xlsx2(Correlation.df,fname ,"Correlation",row.names = FALSE)
  write.xlsx2(Covariance.df, fname, "Covariance",row.names = FALSE,append = TRUE)
  file.rename(fname, file)
                              }
                          )
```

The problem is there can launch a save window with the correct file name, but nothing is saved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `downloadHandler` does not provide a `content` function. This works for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    downloadLink('downloadData', 'Download')
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    df1 <- data.frame(
      A = 1:5, Source = "df1",
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    df2 <- data.frame(
      A = 6:10, Source = "df2",
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function(file) {
        paste0("samplefile", ".xlsx")
      },
      content = function(con) {
        write.xlsx2(df1, con, sheetName = "df1", row.names = FALSE)
        write.xlsx2(df2, con, sheetName = "df2", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
      }
    )
  }
)

runApp(app)
```

Comment: Could you tell me how can I specify the directory that I want to save the Excel? In the popped out window I can drive to the directory but still nothing can be saved there. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean. This works perfectly fine for me -- I can download the file and view it in Excel as expected. Please be more descriptive of your problem.

Comment: Could you specify where to save the file while you click the button? My problem is even I choose specific directory, the file cannot be saved there. I print out the variable "con" is somewhere like `"C:\\Users\\zren\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp4oqYoR\\file22cc3e7d6d5a.xlsx"` (even I already select a different directory like the "Desktop")

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the file cannot be saved there". When I click the 'Download' link, a Windows Explorer dialogue box opens up in my browser allowing me to choose where to save the file. Maybe your web browser preferences are set to automatically save downloads to the 'Downloads' folder?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I figure out myself. It turned out that the build-in browser in Shiny probably has certain bugs to prevent me from saving file in the location I choose. **Let me know if you figure out that part**. It works when I switch to the real browser. (e.g. IE, chrome)